# How can I move Google contacts between two different accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-contacts, contacts

I want to move some contacts, using drag-n-drop, between two Gmail accounts. How can I do this?

Please mind that I do not want to import/export all contacts, I just want to move some of them between two accounts.

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to GMail account one and switch to contacts view
2. Mark the contacts you want to export
3. Select "export" and then "Selected contacts (*n*)" (*n* is the number of contacts you're exporting)
4. Select Google CSV format and export
5. Log out of this account and log in to the second Gmail account. Switch to contacts view
6. Import the file you saved at step 4

Not drag and drop - but quite fast, and you get a backup of those contacts for the same price :)

Comment: I suppose that after you do the export, you loose the selection, si you will have to manually reselect them in order to delete them. Also export does loose pictures.

Comment: No, you don't lose the selection.

Comment: Is it correct that the contact's photo won't be moved this way?

Comment: From my experience, the photo is copied as well

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Unfortunately, no.

Comment: "loose" != "lose"

Comment: @AlEverett you are correct :)

Comment: Pedantically, this is a *copy*, not a *move*. You still need to delete them from the original account separately.

Answer (score 0):

I can use my android phone which has both accounts on it as follows:

1. Open the contact.
2. From menu select Send Vcard via text or email to yourself
3. Save the vcard to phone
4. Find where the phone saved the vcard - on my phone it is in the folder download on the sdcard
5. Open vcard
6. Select the google account you want to save the contact to

Comment: That's fine if one has an Android device, but is completely unhelpful otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The accurate answer is that you cannot.

There are various methods whereby you can make the process of copying contacts from one account to another, but that requires you to copy them, and then delete them on the old account. It's not the same as a move.

Personally, for a one or two contacts, I logged into both gmail accounts at the same time, and copied and pasted the data. For more contacts, the export method suggested by Traveling Tech Guy seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

My way find after long time but easy. I hope it helps.
[How to migrate contacts from google to google account](https://youtu.be/vywmjVcTvuk?list=PL1sq-ZTzDlzKK9ITdXd6o_FNjCpDS780D)

Comment: Adding essential contents from the link into answer would be more helpful to readers.

Comment: As an example of the importance of serenesat's comment, the video is now gone

Answer (score -1):

if you have an Android device, I've found the app [Copy Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alefsoft.copycontacts) to be handy for this.

You can choose multiple contacts in one account, copy them, and paste them all into the second account pretty quickly. You can also filter my contact group when selecting which works well for me (since I am usually copying my friends group from work to personal).